# How to copy files using kohsuke github

Tags: api, file, github, addition

I am working with org.kohsuke.github.*;

1. I have a sample repository where I have a commit (sha) with a bunch of files which serve as a template.
2. When I get a request on my app with a repo name xyz, I need to fork repo xyz, grab files from #1 add the files to the forked repo and submit a PR from forked repo to original repo xyz.

Is this possible via kohsuke github?

Gone through documentation of kohsuke

```
  public static GHRepository createFork(String repo) throws IOException{
        GHRepository mainRepo = github.getRepository(repo);
        GHRepository forkedRepo = mainRepo.fork();
        GHCommit commit = copyFiles();
        /*QUESTION: Here is where I need help. Now that I have the 
         commit that has the files I need how to I add them to 
        forkedRepo?******** */
        GHCommitBuilder builder = forkedRepo.createCommit();
        return forkedRepo;
    }

    public static GHCommit copyFiles() throws IOException {
        GHRepository mainRepo = github.getRepository("sandbox/xyz");
        /* xxxxxxxxx is the sha of commit that has templated files.        
        GHCommit commit = mainRepo.getCommit("xxxxxxxxxxx"); 

        GHContent content = new GHContent();
        return commit;
    }
```